# Prevent an app from launching twice

Tags: unity-game-engine, mutex, multiple-instances

I'm working with Unity3d and am wondering if there is a way to prevent the application from being able to be launched twice on the same computer. I've seen posts using a Mutex but was wondering if there is a builtin option for this in Unity !

Do I absolutely have to use a Mutex ? If so are there any drawbacks to using a Mutex ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to the PlayerSettings for your application (Edit > Project settings > Player) you will have a toggle named "Force Single Instance".

> [image]

Checking this will make sure that upon load of your application it will check if an instance is already running. If so, it will prevent a second instance from starting.

The documentation provides some more detail for the [scripting side of PlayerSettings](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerSettings-forceSingleInstance.html).

Comment: Don't know how I missed that. Thanks !

Comment: I found the setting in the manual, but I just couldn't see it in the settings - thanks for the image!